# How to call a Javascript after a div is replaced?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

I dynamically have to call a Javascript after a  tag is rendered. Is it possible? I am doing some Ajax call which on return should repaint a DIV tag. And it is repainting successfully. I need to fire a Javascript method AFTER the DIV tag is repainted. How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code you are using to re-render the DIV.

Comment: @Pekka : Its a bit complicated, its in Ruby on rails..

Comment: And @Bragboy you may want to clarify your question. Maybe "How to call Javascript after a div is replaced?"

Comment: @Pekka: Made the modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// I am doing some Ajax call 
function ajax( url ) {
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
       // ...
    };

    // which on return should repaint a DIV tag. 
    div.modify();

    // I need to fire a Javascript method AFTER the DIV tag is repainted.
    javascriptMethod();
}
```

Or am I missing something here? :) Maybe you want to do the painting thing when the request is finished, but still i don't see any problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: directly it ain't possible (there is no "repaint" or "change" event on DIVs).

However using jQuery or other JS framework that supports custom events you could add an event listener on the div and fire an event in your AJAX call (i suppose it the onSuccess function; so as the last action inside fire custom event).

Even more simply you could just call the desired JavaScript method after you finish changing your DIV.

Comment: +1 a custom event will be the best thing to do here. You'll have to trigger it manually but there simply is no way to do this cross-browser with a native event.